# How should I deal with texture bleeding?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I was painting a Skorpion gun I modeled until I came across a roadblock - It is not very apparent on the actual image, but when applying the normal map of the model in unreal, I get a bad normal seam due to an almost invisible texture bleed. It "Seems" (no pun intended) that since there are some pixels that are half-in, half-out of the UV islands, that the outcome is a few select pixels that cause seams. And what's worse, they cannot be painted over, since they are not considered to be part of the island. I would appreciate any and all help, in order for me to get back to my active development. Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you add some images to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, I lost that texture. But I'm currently trying hard to reproduce it.

Comment: Ajwood, I have a reproduction of the issue, as It is apparent in unreal:http://imgur.com/Cu0pw7p

Comment: Maybe increasing the marging while baking or fixing it manually with Photoshop?

Comment: Hi everyone,  I found that actually the cause was my uv islands were too tightly packed together, and as a result some islands were even sharing the same pixels. Thanks again!